# #tag のブロック内で、最後のタグしか出力されない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html

rails 5.2.3を使用しています。
下記のようなhtmlを、decorator（active_decorator）から出力させようとしています。

```
.badge.badge-info
  = hoge
  .badge.badge-warning= fuga
```

しかし、下記のように書くと、hogeの部分が出力されません。

```
tag.div(class: 'badge badge-info') do
  hoge
  tag.div fuga, class: 'badge badge-warning'
end
```

hogeの部分も出力させるには、どう書けば良いのでしょうか？

**実際のコード**

view

```
= vacation.badge
```

decorator

```
module VacationDecorator

  def badge
    tag.div(class: 'badge badge-info') do
      off_type_i18n
      tag.div aasm_state_i18n, class: 'badge badge-warning'
    end
  end
```

**出力されたhtml**

```
<div class="badge badge-info"><div class="badge badge-warning">申請中</div></div>
```

blockの中の２行を入れ替えると、今度は

```
<div class="badge badge-info">忌引き休暇</div>
```

となってしまいます。
欲しいのは下記のhtmlです。

```
<div class='badge badge-info'>
  忌引き休暇
  <div class='badge badge-warning'>申請中</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(
hoge +
tag.div(fuga, class: 'badge badge-warning')
).html_safe
```

slim と ruby ではそもそも処理系が違うので
slim の中では羅列文字列がそのまま出力されるけど
ruby の中では順番に実行されてるだけで
結果として返るのは return のみ（省略された場合は最後の行の返り値）
でそれを slim がレンダリングしてるに過ぎない

ruby 内で羅列した（返り値が文字列の）もの全部出力するには
単純に ＋ か concat でつないで返り値に含めればいい
タグとして認識させたい場合は最後に html_safe をつける

```
[
  hoge,
  tag.div(fuga, class: 'badge badge-warning')
].join.html_safe
```

とかやるとちょっとかっこいいかも

Comment: +, concat, join いずれでもうまくいきました！